# How to consolidate log4j alerts?

Tags: log4j, logback

Our application sends out log4j emails when an Exception is thrown. Because we're doing batch processing, the exception may occur every minute (or more often) until the error is resolved.

Is there a way to set up log4j so that it buffers exceptions and consolidates them? So that we can deuce the number of email alerts that get sent out?

Would also accept a third party service or nagios plugin that can do this sort of consolidation.

I am envisioning that even though exceptions go thrown every minute for an hour, we have some tool, service, or other mechnaism that can consolidate log4j logs (or any application error log that gets emailed out) so that we have more control over alerts.

The goal is to reduce noise of alerts going out to the ops folks. They need to know the alert occurred and is still occurring, but dont need to be spammed every minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for Logback. There is a plan to include support for log4j.
Have a look at the new Whisper appender: [Whisper on Github](http://eclecticlogic.github.io/whisper/).

*Statutory disclaimer: I'm the author.*